# What is an average estimate for the energy between molecules (crystal bonding energies) in an ice sphere as a function of temperature?

Tags: collision, ice

To give some context, during collision between ice particles, it might be that some parts of the particles splinter off. I am trying to quantify that by a gross assumption that the latter is determined by the ratio between the transferred kinetic energy and the total bonding energy.

Comment: It seems like you could estimate this from the latent heat of vaporization.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? @Chemomechanics

Comment: The latent heat of vaporization represents the energy needed to completely break molecules apart. That’s what happens in evaporation/sublimation.

Comment: I do not believe this parameter is the only one to be considered, because what you said is true only under a very special set of thermodynamics